# when using @media in css div disappears

Tags: css, responsive-design, resize, media-queries

My screen is divided in half, left=73% and right=23%
Now I use @media for big screens to make it 60% and 40% above 1200px

But the right side disappears when I resize above 1200px

And I don't understand why

A simple example https://jsfiddle.net/quorton/v67zo9mx/
If you resize the browser the right side disappears

I tried IE and chrome (latest versions)

```
    <html>
<body id="body" >
    <form id="form" method="post" action="">
        <div id="left">
            text
        </div>
        <div id="right" style="background:blue;">
            <div>
                text2
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>        
</html>
```

CSS

```
    @media screen and (max-width: 400px){
    #left {
        float: left;
        padding-left: 1%;
        width: 73%;
        height: 100vh;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 401px){
    #left {
        float: left;
        padding-left: 1%;
        width: 60%;
        height: 100vh;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
    #right {
        float: right;
        padding-right: 1%;
        width: 23%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 401px){
    #right {
        float: right;
        padding-right: 1%;
        width: 40%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It doesn’t disappear, it just is at the bottom of the page because you have the left side with a width of 60 % + 1 % `padding-left` and the right side with a width of 40 % + 1 % of `padding-right`, which is, in addition, 102 % and thus too much to be displayed next to each other.

And it’s the same for the responsive version, just with other values.

Recalculate your values of the left and the right div to get the elements next to each other.

For example:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
    #left {
        float: left;
        padding-left: 1%;
        width: 72%;
        height: 100vh;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 401px){
    #left {
        float: left;
        padding-left: 1%;
        width: 59%;
        height: 100vh;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 400px){
    #right {
        float: right;
        padding-right: 1%;
        width: 22%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 401px){
    #right {
        float: right;
        padding-right: 1%;
        width: 39%;
    }
}
```

Comment: [insert swear word] you are completely right and I should have seen this. I was under the impression both widths were a 100%, so I added 60/40 for the bigger screen, not noticing 73+23 = 96

Comment: Nobody’s perfect. Would be great if you set my answer as accepted answer (click on the check sign on the left of my answer) so that other people can also see that this is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the fix. **Box-sizing**

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 400px) {
  #left {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 1%;
    width: 73%;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  #right {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 1%;
    width: 23%;
  }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 401px) {
  #left {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 1%;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100vh;
  }
  #right {
    float: right;
    padding-right: 1%;
    width: 40%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="left" style="background:gray;">
  text
</div>
<div id="right" style="background:yellow;">
  <div>
    text2
  </div>
</div>
```